# List all files in a google drive... but no folders or shortcuts or xxxx

Tags: google-drive-api

If I wanted to find the IDs of files in a google folder, how could I write that query.  I want to exclude folders, shortcuts and anything else that isn't a file.. now or in the future (ie, if google adds a new mime type object that isn't a file).

It sounds simple.. maybe it is.  But I don't want to have to keep a list of mime types and if it's a file or not to query against when building the drive.  It would be nice if there was a higher level "type" descriptor like "file".  But even a folder is a kind "drive#file".

Example:

```
/Folder1
   file1 (shortcut)
   file1 (google doc)
   file1 (sheet)
   /file1 (subfolder)
```

Do I need to specifically select certain mime types... or exclude certain mime types if I wanted the results to only return the google doc and sheet?  Or is there some other attribute I can query over to subselect only "files".

One thing I have found is folders and shortcuts do not have a "size" attribute.  That may be something that I can use... but I want to make sure there's not something else.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `This is something I am aware of already.`, I couldn't notice that you have already known my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, I understand that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I think that I have to study English more. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude folders from query use this: mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'

```
.setQ("mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
```

source: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files?hl=en